# Is there an RSS feed of Ubuntu Release torrent files

Tags: bittorrent, rss, release-management

A lot of torrent search engines have the ability to provide an RSS feed of matches, allowing you to set up torrent programs to download items which are published on the feed. This is useful for watching releases of things.

The problem with doing this through a random search engine for Ubuntu is that you usually get too many torrents as it picks up different custom versions, and other software with the name in the title/description. See: http://www.mininova.org/rss/ubuntu

So I was wondering if there was an RSS feed somewhere that only loads up the official torrent files for releases?

So from the responses, there doesn't appear to be an existing RSS feed that does what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering this simply so it can have an answer...

No, there is currently no RSS feed of releases.

Answer (score 3):

## Linux Tracker

[LinuxTracker.org](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=torrents&category=563) has been around since 2004:

- [Register](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=signup) and [Get RSS](http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=modules&module=getrss)
- Or use the Anonymous Ubuntu Feed: http://linuxtracker.org/rss_torrents.php?feed=dl&cat[]=563&pid=00000000000000000000000000000000

## DistroWatch

[DistroWatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=bittorrent) has been around since 2001:

- https://distrowatch.com/news/torrents.xml

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that helps but you could use the [metalink](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/metalink) file which can be found here: [Daily- builds](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)

as you can see in this file there is a link in `./files/file/resource/url` wich points to the latest torrent.

Comment: But that isn't for monitoring and waiting for new releases to become available, instead it's for a specific release, right?

Comment: @Valorin as you know the release cycle is 6 months. So you could try to watch for the metalink in (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/release/) until it won't return a 404 what implies that the release has landend ;)

Comment: Yes, but that won't work in a standard Torrent program's RSS feed watcher. The entire point of my question is if there is an existing RSS feed of ubuntu releases so people can configure their Torrent programs to automatically download them when released. I guess the answer is, no, there is no RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you bookmark the Ubuntu.com ( http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) you will see it in seconds. This is what I do with google chromes bookmark and the 24 links ( you will have to drag from page to page. ) on the page. instant access. Or you can get a igoogle page from your gmail account. I hope this is helpful to you.